# Do Something Based on Attribute Set Name in Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, set

I've had a look around and can't seem to find the exact answer I'm after here, so I've made a new post.

I need to display specific HTML on the product list page based on whether a collection has a specific attribute set assigned.

There are 4 attribute sets that products can have, 'Clothing', 'Boots', 'Bags' and 'Accessories'.

So, if the collection has either the 'Bags' or 'Accessories' atrribute set I want to display one thing and anything else I want to display another. My code so far is:

```
<?php 
                    $bags = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)->addFilter('attribute_set_name', 'Bags');
                    $accessories = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)->addFilter('attribute_set_name', 'Accessories');

                    $size_default = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_clothes_fr = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_clothes_fr') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_clothes_uk = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_clothes_uk') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_clothes_us = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_clothes_us') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_clothes_it = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_clothes_it') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_shoes_default = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_shoe') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_shoes_fr = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_shoes_fr') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_shoes_it = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_shoes_it') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_shoes_uk = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_shoes_uk') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                    $size_shoes_us = $_product -> getResource() -> getAttribute('size_shoes_us') -> getFrontend() -> getValue($_product);
                ?>
                <?php if(trim($bags) || trim($accessories)) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" class="product-image"><?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(140, 255); ?>" width="140" height="255" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId() ; ?>" /><?php endif; ?><?php if(!$_product->isSaleable()): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/masks/white80.png') ?>" width="140" height="255" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId() ; ?>" style="background:url('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(140, 255); ?>') no-repeat center center" /><?php endif; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="sizes">
                    <a class="trigger" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" class="product-image"><?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(140, 255); ?>" width="140" height="255" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId() ; ?>" /><?php endif; ?><?php if(!$_product->isSaleable()): ?><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/masks/white80.png') ?>" width="140" height="255" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId() ; ?>" style="background:url('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(140, 255); ?>') no-repeat center center" /><?php endif; ?></a>
                    <div class="popup">
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_default ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_clothes_fr ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_clothes_it ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_clothes_us ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_clothes_uk ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_shoes_default ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_shoes_fr ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_shoes_it ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_shoes_uk ;?></p>
                        <p class="size_title"><?php echo $size_shoes_us ;?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

It doesn't seem to work though, it always displays the else statement regardless. I'm obviously not doing something right here. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (if you haven't already solved it) is likely because your collections aren't returning the correct data. What you're getting is essentially a collection of attribute sets, filtered by their name. That's going to be the same every time because you're not involving the product at any point.

Try getting the name this way:

```
$attSetName = Mage::getModel(’eav/entity_attribute_set’) 
    ->load($_product->getAttributeSetId()) 
    ->getAttributeSetName();
```

And then compare that variable like this:

```
if ($attSetName == "bags" || $attSetName == "accessories") {
```

If you were intending on returning a collection, you might also encounter issues because you're using the "trim()" php function. Trim is intended for strings, so trimming a collection object probably won't do what you want it to do. Try this instead:

```
if (count($bags) > 0 || count($accessories) > 0) {
```